# Minimum movements to arrange fruits in boxes

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, permutation, probability

I have 3 boxes - B1, B2, B3. Each box initially contains a mixture of 3 different kind of fruits say - Apple, Orange, Mango. Our goal is to arrange the fruits in the boxes in such a manner that each box contains only one type of fruit. So you need to shift fruits from one box to another in order to make the arrangement. How to do this with minimum number of movements?

Say 9 integers are given. As each box initially contains all 3 types of fruits, you can divide 9 integers into 3 groups, each group representing the initial permutation of fruits in B1, B2, B3 respectively. Consider: 10, 17, 20, 32, 29, 19, 43, 27, 28. Fruits are represented in order of Apple, Orange & Mango. So The first box contains 10 Apple, 17 Orange & 20 Mango and so on.

What is the minimum number of movements required so that the mentioned boxes contain only one type of fruit. Any box can contain any 1 type of fruit.

Comment: I solved it with sorting but I don't think that's a good option as there may be multiple possible combination with same output. So what is the mathematical base behind it and how to get all possible combinations?

Comment: What is a "*movement*"? it is not clear. Also does the initial arrangement matter or not (e.g inital configuration is always the same)

Comment: Can we move more than one at the same time?

Comment: No only one fruit at a time.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this by expressing it as an assignment problem and then using the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to find the optimal solution.  This would have complexity O(n^3) where n is the number of boxes.

To express it as an assignment, view the problem as trying to assign a label to each box showing its final contents.  The score for that assignment is given by the number of the fruit that are not currently contained in the box.

So for example, if the first box contains 10 Apple, 17 Orange, and 20 Mango, and there are a total of 85 Apples, then the cost of assigning the Apple label to the first box is 85-10 = 75.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 6 possibilities to assign labels to your 3 boxes:

1. apples, oranges, mango
2. apples, mango, oranges
3. oranges, apples, mango
4. oranges, mango, apples
5. mango, apples, oranges
6. mango, oranges, apples

For each of these permutations you can do some kind of addition to find the movement cost. For example for permutation 1 you need to move all the apples not in box 1, all the oranges not in box 2 and all the mangos not in box 3. So that's adding the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 6th, 7th and 8th number from your input.

Make a similar addition for each of the permutations, then choose the permutation that scores lowest.

There is no need/use for any kind of fancy algorithm here unless you want to make a generalisation for n boxes.

Comment: But it's a brute force approach. Minimizing the cost of calculation is also important here.

Comment: Yes it's brute force, but why wouldn't you brute force it if that only takes 30 additions and 5 comparisons? You can reduce it a bit by storing some temporary answers in a new variable, but that's only worth it if you really want to minimize the use of + and somehow can create new variables at no cost.